# Github how to recover overwritten new code with old code

Tags: github

By trying to update my github repo, I accidentally overwritten the NEW code with the Old code. so in result all the new code is gone.
any way to get it back?

Comment: There might be a discrepancy between your definition of "new" and "old" and git's :-) Can you elaborate on the git history of commits?

Comment: thanks for commenting, i had the new code in my pc, wanted to push it to github, i had some irrelevant problems, so what happends i pulled the OLD version to my pc, and the NEW version got overwritten.

Comment: You cannot pull changes when you have unstaged local changes. When you removed the local changes without committing them, they cannot be restored.

Comment: I suggest to use something like SourceTree or Fork and when you have changes that make problems - put them in the "git stash", pull changes, then apply the stashed changes.